Authorization policy for API key authentication without authentication scheme in ASP.NET Core 8
I want to add API key authentication to my API using an authorization policy but I get the error No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
Is there a way to do this?
I don't need any cookie/JWT authentication, the API key will be sent as a header.
This is my configuration:
public class ApiKeyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public ApiKeyRequirement()
    {
    }
}

public class ApiKeyHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IConfiguration configuration) : AuthorizationHandler<ApiKeyRequirement>
{
    private readonly string apiKey = configuration["Credentials:ApiKey"] ?? throw new Exception("No API key was found");

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ApiKeyRequirement requirement)
    {
        string? receivedApiKey = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.Request.Headers["x-api-key"];

        if (receivedApiKey != apiKey)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ApiKey", policy =>
    {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new ApiKeyRequirement());
    });
});

//...

app.UseAuthorization();


Hi @iKingNinja, could you pls share how is your ApiKeyRequirement? Also how do you create a handler?

Hi @Rena I updated by question with the requirement and handler's code. Although I don't think that has anything to do with the error I'm getting since it looks like that is happening because authorization policies require an authentication scheme


but I get the error No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).

You dont' want any cookie/JWT authentication, only send the API key as a header. What you did actually can work fine if you send the correct api key by testing your code. For why you receive the error may be caused by you send the wrong api key or you do not send the api key in the header.
You need set breakpoint to your ApiKeyHandler to check if the api key is correct or not:

Reference:First look at the Visual Studio Debugger
